# Why do features in QGIS drawn on same datum as Google imagery from OpenLayers move?

Tags: qgis, google-maps, qgis-plugins, georeferencing

I have just started using QGIS. I've loaded the "openlayers" plugin and added a google hybrid layer, which is based off the WGS84 datum to my understanding. Now I create a shapefile and add a new line vector layer based on the same datum. I draw a line and then zoom out. Now, the line has moved with regards to the google map (i'm drawing a road and now the road no longer lines up with the original road I'm using for a guide).

My end goal is to make a georeferenced shapefile with some roads. Is my methodology flawed or is their a problem with my plugin (assuming the former of course!)?

Comment: Just another case of this bug: http://hub.qgis.org/issues/6822

Comment: Google's layers are served on the [EPSG:3857](http://spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/6864/) CRS, that uses a sphere as datum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, when you'll try to capture a vector data (no mater it's a point, a line or a polygon), using the `Google Satelite` map as the background layer, you will notice unpleasant displacements at different zoom levels:

[image]

But the beauty of the `OpenLayers` plugin is due to the fact it loads a lot of other useful maps to do your job. I recommend you to use the `Bing Road` map (the line keeps its position when changing the zoom level):

[image]

Comment: It should also be noted that this is against the Google's terms of services for using their base layers as far as I am aware.